# managing a specific version curl output in php from URL

Tags: php, curl

How do I get the output from curl in PHP?

My code as it stands is the following:

```
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://specific.com/version.yaml");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            $result = preg_match("/(?:version|)\s*((?:[0-9]+\.?)+)/i", $result);
            echo $result
```

My yaml file looks like this

```
version: 3.3.5.1
files:
    add:
        - {local: "styles/admin/default/subnavigation/index.php", remote: "/subnavigation.html"}
        - {local: "styles/admin/default/subnavigation/manage.php", remote: "/subnavigationmanage.html"}
        - {local: "styles/admin/default/servers/manage.php", remote: "/servers_manage.html"}
```

I want the output

```
3.3.5.1
```

But with this code i get only "1" as output.
If i delete the preg_match, i get the full code as output.
Can you help me?

Comment: What do you get if you remove your preg_match()? Do you get the contents? There are also better ways to get data from yaml than using regular expressions. You can install and enable PHP's [yaml extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.yaml.php) or use a [library](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/yaml) to parse it for you. That will be way less error prone.

Comment: if i remove the preg, i have the full output "version: 3.3.5.1 files: add: - {local: "styles/admin/default/subnavigation..."

Comment: Then your issue doesn't have anything to do with cURL (since it returns the result just fine) but with your regex. You should edit your question to reflect that (and include the regex tag so all regex-masters sees the question), or just parse the yaml using any of the suggested methods in the first comment.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found a solution

```
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            preg_match_all("/(?:version|)\s*((?:[0-9]+\.?)+)/i", $result, $matches);
            $i = 0;
            foreach($matches as $resulte) {
                if(++$i > 1) break;
                echo $resulte[0];
            }
```